# How to update page information of Nodejs app deployed using Heroku free hosting on a daily basis?

Tags: node.js, heroku, scheduler

I have a nodejs app which needs to fetch some data (download a picture to the server and fetch some related text) from an API once a day at midnight and updates the fields my `index.ejs` file.

Unfortunately because of restrictions around the free Heroku accounts, my app goes to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity, so I can't use a cron-job for this.

I tried heroku scheduler, but it doesn't work. I added `node server.js` as a job, but it doesn't run it. I tried removing the job and adding it again, but it didn't work. My app runs fine in local environment, or when I initially push it to heroku, or when I do `heroku run node server.js`.

I tried the creating a separate server file with no JS extension and added `#!/usr/bin/env node` to the but it said "bash command not found" when I tried to `heroku run node server.js`.

I'm really confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers